# Access Github secrets in workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I have a few secrets stored in my repo and I want to access those secrets in workflow on a **pull request** but,  I don't want to use **pull_request_target** because it gives write access on my repo and it leads to security risk is there anything by which, I can accomplish this task.

Comment: You can configure an activity type for most of the triggers, for `pull_request` as well. I suggest to take a look here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request to check if setting them can resolve your issue 

Comment: yeah thanx for the help but  I am able to solve the issue by using a workflow run